# Catalyst voting power not including staking rewards?

Tags: catalyst, voting

Why did my voting power not include all of my staking rewards during Fund3 or Fund4 voting?

My catalyst app shows less voting power than what my Daedalus wallet has in balance (and had in balance on the June 11th 2021 snapshot).
The difference it is roughly the staking rewards I accrued during the Shelley mainnet.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like it does not at this time. If you use Yoroi and move the rewards over from the reward key to the main wallet that is one work around. The other would be to have a tx on Daedalus as that seems to consolidate from the staking key as well to the main wallet.

However, I'm not sure about future versions of catalyst which could change how this functions and perhaps not need to do the above.

Answer (score 0):

To confirm (18 months later) - this is still the way the catalyst app works. I'm not sure why it does not take the "unspent" staking rewards into account, it would seem like a pretty sensible idea for it to include them. However, Daedalus users will need to make a transaction to claim the staking rewards into the main wallet.

You could, for example, send a couple of Ada to Coinbase, Binance, etc. You can always send them back if you want to. You'll notice the wallet balance in Daedalus will update and the "unspent rewards" will change to 0.

[image: unspent rewards]

It's not clear how quickly the Catalyst app will refresh the wallet balance though - I assume it doesn't refresh on a regular basis but I have no doubt that the snapshot will be correct when it takes place.

Comment: The most simple way to move the staking rewards to your wallet in Daedalus would be to send some ADA to your own wallet. No need to send them to a third party.

Comment: @eddex you mean send from your wallet to the same wallet you're sending from? For some reason I assumed you couldn't send to the same wallet you're sending from but thinking about it I can't see why not

Comment: Exactly. You go to "receive", copy your address, go to "send", paste your address and send e.g. 1 ADA to your own address.